# How to redirect vscode c++ stdout to debug output?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode for debugging my c++ program, everything works fine except that the output of my program goes to *Terminal* instead of *Debug console*.

When I type commands in the *Debug console* to print something, such as `xxx.dump()`, the output goes to *Terminal*. I have to keep switching between the two panels, which is a little annoying.

How can I redirect the output from *Terminal* to *Debug console*? Or can I have both the two panels on my screen simultaneously?

I am using *C/C++* extension for debugging (with default configuration). More specifically, I want the below code to print to *Debug console* instead of *Terminal*.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is my full configuration. I'm using *Remote - SSH* extension to code on a remote linux server (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS).

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Simple debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I just realised that you can have them side by side. [Similar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Aty.gif)  You just need to drag the terminal and place it on left/right. Can you post your `launch.json` file?

Comment: @brc-dd Yes! I can drag them, thank you very much!